# Rules for Choosing Bounds and Initial Conditions when Using 2nd Order Runge Kutta Methods

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, recursive-algorithms, runge-kutta-methods

I have a question regarding 2nd order Runge-Kutta methods, specifically where it regards the bounds of the solution.

Let's say I have to solve a 1st order ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x,y)$ numerically using Heun's method:

$$y_{i+1}=y_i+\frac{1}{2}h(k_1+k_2)$$
$$k_1=f(x_i,y_i), k_2=f(x_i+h,y_i+k_1h)$$

The ODE can be solved within a range let's say $a<x<b$. **My question is whether the initial condition needs to coincide with $x=a$ or whether it only needs between the bounds.**

Here is an example I was messing around with when I noticed the potential issue.

Solve the following ODE using Heun's method within the bounds $a<x<b$ with a step size of $h=0.2$.
$$xy^\prime+y=x\sin(x), y(\pi)=2$$

1. If the range is $1<x<3$ where $x_0=\pi$ is outside of the range the numerical error is very high giving the following plot after calculating in MATLAB. *I noticed the shape of the approximation was similar to the exact solution.*
   [image: 1<x<3]
2. If I change the range to $3<x<5$ so that $x_0=\pi$ falls within the range, the error is significantly smaller. **Is this because $a<x_0<b$ or is it because $\pi\approx3$ and I should have started at $x_0=3$?**
   [image: 3<x<5]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one function that solves the IVP, regardless for which interval you produce the function table/plot.

So for the first plot you would use the nodes $x=\pi,3,2.8,2.6,...$ with the step size the difference between the nodes, always negative and after the first step $-0.2$.

For the second plot you need one step backwards to $x=3$ and then forwards, either from $x=3$ or from $x=\pi$ to the next node $x=3.2$.

The error in all this should be smaller than $0.05$ or $5\%$, so probably well visible but very close to the exact solution.

Comment: Thank you, This is helpful but it does not answer my question about whether the initial condition must coincide with $x=a$ or just be within the bounds. It explains the small error which is something I already deduced from the plots because $\pi$ is so close to 3.

Comment: The initial condition is the initial condition, it selects the solution function. If you somehow mix that with the left boundary of the integration interval, you compute sometimes the wrong solution. The naive, standard time loop only applies if $x_0=a$, if you go outside of that you need to cobble together an adapted time loop or two.

Comment: OK, I see. That wasn't clear from your original explanation but now I see it. Thanks.